# XPath expression exception

Tags: javascript, xpath, xul

I am not really sure if i am doing this right with XPath expression. I am trying to locate a  text on DOM and this text is assingned to a variable. I have text stored in SQLite and i have retrievd the text and i am trying to locate it on the webpage which actually contains the text. so i ahve the following code:

```
var searchText = dataset[x]['selectedText'];
        alert(dataset[x]['selectedText']);
        var res = googbar_frames[0].contentDocument.evaluate("//*[.=searchText]",googbar_frames[0].contentDocument.body,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
        alert(res.snapshotLength);
```

And i get the following error.

```
Error: Permission denied for <http://en.wikipedia.org> to call method XPathException.toString on <>.
Error: Permission denied for <http://en.wikipedia.org> to call method XPathException.toString on <>.
```

Have got the expression correct. I am trying to look for the text on DOM. Or am i going wrong somwehere?
cheers

Comment: Need more code. What is `googbar_frames`? Where is this code getting called from?

Answer (score 2):

[This is an answer to [a followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625185/xpath-expression-exception#1628748) to [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625185/xpath-expression-exception#1625389). Sorry, stackoverflow purists! The comments thingie doesn't always work.]

Yes, this is what I talked about earlier. `".//text()[contains(.,searchText)]"` doesn't use the JavaScript variable `searchText`, it's just a string.

You could construct the XPath expression using `searchText`. There's no [variable interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28programming%29#Interpolation) in JS, so you have to construct the XPath expression using manual concatenation, like this:

```
var xpathExpr = ".//text()[contains(.,'" + searchText + "')]";
```

...**except this fails** if searchText includes a single quote ('), so you have to escape it and possibly other characters with special meaning in this context in XPath. I'm not up to figuring out for you what exactly and how you need to escape in searchText, it would involve either searching the internets for an existing solution or reading the xpath spec to learn the grammar in this case.

So I stick with my original reply:

> what are you actually trying to do? Perhaps using the interfaces the Firefox Find toolbar uses would be a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

[This is the original answer to the question, see also a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625185/xpath-expression-exception#1628748) and [an answer to the follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625185/xpath-expression-exception#1625389)]

The expression is incorrect. Running this (i.e. using a correct expression) in the browser.xul context:

```
 content.document.evaluate("//*[.=searchText]",
   content.document.body,null,XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null);
```

- while not very useful, produces no such exception.

Do you actually include `searchText` in the XPath expression? Is it quoted properly? I expect your XPath results will not be what you expect it to be, so what are you actually trying to do? Perhaps using the interfaces the Firefox Find toolbar uses would be a better idea?

Comment: hey ,
what do you mean by include searchText in the XPath expression?

var searchText = dataset[x]['selectedText']; // that code their retrieves a text e.g football from the database. so the text to be searched is 'football'.
and as for the contentDocument thing, i ahve got frames in the main browser and its intended for firefox.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes i did manage to get what i wanted. and that answer was of great help.